# Not all logical volumes appears during installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 and 22.04.2

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, lvm, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 from the live USB stick.
I have 3 existing volume groups (LVM).
Some of the partitions has been created with Ubuntu 18.04 (and probably ealier versions too). I can see all of them.
Using the shell from the live USB, I have created 4 more logical volumes on 2 different volume groups (the partitions on which I need to install Ubuntu). I can create file system on it (BTRFS) and mount them. However, after reboot, they don't appear in the list of available devices.
I tried from the regular Ubuntu Desktop, the installer can see them (but the installation leave a broken system because it doesn't add necessary modules).

I can reproduce this behavior with Ubuntu 20.04.6.

Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks for your help.